# How to create onOpen() function on all worksheets inserted or created in a workspace with GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following function that creates a menun in a spreadsheet:

```
function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 ui.createMenu('Scripts')
   .addItem('Label1', 'function1')
   .addSeparator()
   .addItem('Label2', 'function2')
   .addSeparator()
   .addItem('Label3', 'function3')
   .addToUi();
}
```

I have a workspace and I would like all worksheets inserted or created in that workspace to receive this onOpen() function automatically. It's possible?

Comment: In your situation, how about using [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest)? At first, it retrieves all Spreadsheet IDs you want to use. And, create new GAS project using the method of projects.create. And then, put the script to the created GAS project using the method of projects.updateContent. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Please show what you tried to accomplish your goal and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to accomplish. You want any spreadsheet you work on to have this custom menu? I think this could be accomplish by creating an [add-on](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/editors/sheets). Do you think that could be useful in your situation?